# Is the 3 pin plug provided in a cigarette lighter port inverter (12v-220) actually grounded?

Tags: charging, ground, inverter

I have been planning to buy a 12v car inverter, that plugs into the cigarette lighter port and puts out 220v with max 200watts, for sometime now. The one that I ordered is of brand portronics and has a 3 pin plug for charging appliances like laptop etc. I wish to charge my laptop from it but it needs an active grounding. I am skeptical whether the 3rd pin of the inverter is actually grounded or not.

Comment: DC voltage only has 2 wires, hot and ground, no way we can know what that manufacturer has done when converting to AC.

Comment: @Moab Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Don't know I am not an electrical engineer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it may be technically “grounded” to the car but the car is on “rubber” tires so it won’t be grounded in the classic sense.

However, a laptop needing “active” grounding sounds a bit curious... I have had many and the power bricks will happily work with a 2 pin or 3 pin cable - in fact some are designed to swap out a two pin plug for a 2 metre (6 foot) 3 core cable with ground pin and it works properly with either.

Comment: I couldn't follow the later part. My laptop charger has a 3 pin plug as well as the adapter has a 3 pin socket. So if needs a ground connection right? Obviously it will charge without a ground but is it safe? I have destroyed many PCs because of my house's poor ground that is why I am skeptical. It might damage the adapter if not my laptop itself.

Comment: @DhrubaBanerjee with such a famous brand name I would not trust anything... used a cheap chinesium inverter the other week and it lasted 30 seconds... the one I have that is swiss made is 10 years old and doing fine.

Comment: I am more concerned about the 900 dollar laptop than the 30 dollar inverter XD

Comment: @DhrubaBanerjee then if you are so concerned about the laptop you would be buying as better quality inverter...

Comment: Yes I am ditching the idea of buying a modified sine wave inverter.